# passing hard-coded arguments to view in ember.js

Tags: data-binding, ember.js

I am trying to display a simple generic datatable view I'm creating in ember.js.

I would like to pass the columns to it like this:

```
App.MyDatatableView columnsBindings="['col1','col2']" }}
```

or :

```
App.MyDatatableView columnsBindings=['col1','col2'] }}
```

but neither work. In both cases my columns property is 'undefined'.

My view looks like this:

```
App.MyDatatableView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName : 'datatable',
    attributeBindings: ['columns'],
    columns : []
});
```

My other option is to have to inherit from the view, but it would be much nicer if you could just pass the values in the handlebars template.

Thanks for the help,
Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handlebars doesn't support passing in arrays to bindings. You need to pass in a property that holds these column values. For instance in your controller use,

```
App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  columns: function() {
    return ['col1', 'col2'];
  }.property()
});
```

You can then use this `columns` property in the template like,

```
{{MyDatatableView columnsBindings=columns}}
```

### Edit: Handlebars helper.

A handlebars view helper could parse out the columns string in a computed property. For complex parsing you could also use `JSON.parse`, the example just splits on the comma.

The helper registration,

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('MyDatatableView', App.MyDatatableView);
```

The corresponding view with the `cols` computed property.

```
App.MyDatatableView = Ember.View.extend({
  cols: function() {
    return this.get('columns').split(',');
  }.property('columns'),
  didInsertElement: function() {
    console.log('didInsertElement', this.get('cols'));
  }
});
```

Using the helper in a template,

```
{{MyDatatableView columns="col1,col2"}}
```

Comment: I see, thanks. What do you think of passing a string and using JSON.parse()? I don't like having to make an object just to pass some information

Comment: I suppose, You could use `JSON.parse` within a custom Handlebars helper.

Comment: Hmm, do you know how I may extend the view helper easily? As all I need is to add this functionality